# regex in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 'foo,foobar,something'),
        (2, 'bar,fooaaa'),
    ],
    ['id', 'txt']
)
df.show()
```

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                 txt|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|foo,foobar,something|
|  2|    bar,awdaw,fooaaa|
+---+--------------------+
```

Now I want to keep only the lines that have certain words in the column "txt", I get a regex like `regex = '(foo|other)'`.

If I do `df = df.filter(df.txt.rlike(regex))` I also keep line 2 because of "fooaaa".
How can I do this correctly?

**Note**: The regex is an input and arbitrary. I cannot simply add `\b`s here.

I tried `df.select("id", f.split("txt", ",").alias("txt"))`, but then I have a list and I cannot use `rlike` anymore.

```
+---+----------------------+
| id|                   txt|
+---+----------------------+
|  1|[foo,foobar,something]|
|  2|    [bar,awdaw,fooaaa]|
+---+----------------------+
```

Is there a function that searches for a string in a list of strings for each line in a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: So you are only looking for full words?

Comment: Not necessarily, the regex can be arbitrary. But its always between the commas. For example the regex could also be `^fo`, but **not** `,foo`.

Comment: what about an UDF ? did you try ?

Answer (score 1):

I have something that works with your current example but it has tons of limitations. We can do better.

```py
df.withColumn("extract", F.regexp_extract("txt", regex, 0)).where(
    "array_contains(split(txt, ','), extract)"
).show()

+---+--------------------+-------+
| id|                 txt|extract|
+---+--------------------+-------+
|  1|foo,foobar,something|    foo|
+---+--------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spark 2.4+ you can use a combination of [exists](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#exists) and [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#rlike) from the built-in [SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html) after the split. In this way, each element of the array is tested individually with `rlike`.

```python
df.withColumn("flag", F.expr("exists(split(txt, ','), x -> x rlike '^(foo|other)$')")) \
   .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------+-----+
| id|                 txt| flag|
+---+--------------------+-----+
|  1|foo,foobar,something| true|
|  2|          bar,fooaaa|false|
+---+--------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F   

df = spark.createDataFrame(   
    [   
        (1, 'foo,foobar,something'),   
        (2, 'bar,fooaaa'),   
    ],   
    ['id', 'txt']   
)   
regex = '(foobar|other)'   

df.show()
```

| id | txt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo,foobar,something |
| 2 | bar,fooaaa |

```
df.select('id', 'txt').where(F.col('txt').rlike(regex)).show()
```

| id | txt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo,foobar,something |